# SQL how we can count without while loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I want to count frequency rate of stop work hours from 01-01-2020 to the current day ,

I have a table event contain harret column = hours of stop working and a table of employe .
the frequency rate calculation formula is
number of hours of stoppage * 1,000,000 / number of hours worked * number of employees

select SUM (harret) * 1000000 / datedif from event,
select (((cast(now() as date) - '2020-01-01') * 11 )/7 ) * count(*) as datedif from employe

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you want is:

```
select sum(case when extract(isodow from dt) <= 5 then 7.6 else 4 end) as total_working_hours
from generate_series(date '2020-01-01', current_date, '1 day') d(dt)
```

`generate_series()` produces one row per day since the beginning of the year. Then we compute the working hours, as 7.6 hours per week day and 4 hours per week-end day.

Comment: but this gives us 2110 hours for 321 days and if we calculate manually we will find 5XX

Comment: @NouriHamza: your question now is really different from the one your originally asked. Why such a big edit? It invalidates the answer. As for the query, what it does is explained in the answer. You might need to review it to adapat it to your actual use case - which is really unclear to me now after your edit.